# Is a question mark needed at the end of a question if the sentence ends with a period or an exclamation mark?

Tags: punctuation, question-mark

For example, in the two sentences below, are you supposed to end with a question mark?

> Which of Shaw's plays has the line "If only parents would realize how they bore their children!"

And

> Is the next board-meeting going to be held in Washington, D.C.

Edit: Why do I ask? Because the Webster's New World College Dictionary (3rd edition) that I have at home says if two marks of punctuation are needed at the same place within a sentence, 'only the stronger is usually retained'. And they give the first sentence as an example, omitting the question mark. I made up the second example. There's nothing said about how to decide which is stronger.

Comment: The two lines might be made to *look* less awkward if the exclamation mark were omitted in the first and the second used "DC" instead of "D.C.", but a question always ends with a question mark.

Comment: As per my first comment, a question always ends in a question mark, so that must be "stronger" than anything else. When was your dictionary published? Which edition is it?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Sorry, it's actually Webster's New World college dictionary, third edition, and not the Oxford dictionary. (There's no publishing date; just a foreword by the editor in the beginning dated 1996). See image: i.stack.imgur.com/eSY0I.jpg

Comment: It's a good question. However, considering that the Webster's used such an example now makes the question more of a kind of popularity poll: "yes, I *think so*, too" vs. "no, I don't agree." Perhaps OP should write to the editors asking for a clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Both need a question mark:

> Which of Shaw's plays has the line "If only parents would realize how they bore their children!"?
>
> Is the next board-meeting going to be held in Washington, D.C.?